# How to use register users in django that are register in Laravel?

Tags: python, php, django, laravel

The website is develop in Laravel. I want to add some functionalities in it. Kindly help me to that how can i get Users in django that are register in Laravel?

Comment: With this can i access all the existing users? And can i send things from admin panel of django to the users?

Comment: Kindly help i am stick with this problem from 2 days

Comment: If you follow the steps of my answer then you can register user model in the admin and use it’s functionalities (read this for details about the admin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/). Yes you can access existing users with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The database is independent from Laravel, so you can use it with Django. The db table containing users already exists, so you don' t need to make migrations.

First add your database in your Django settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # Database info
    }
}
```

Django can generate models for you by inspecting the database:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Now use the output to create interested models (note that you should refine the result), you need also to create one or more apps to contain model files.

Finally you need to creates some db tables that Django uses internally (for example for permissions):

```
python manage.py migrate
```